# target individual checkbox value

Tags: javascript, checkbox, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a checkbox with 3 Values 
'Father' , 'Mother' and Secretary. I tried to target individual checkboxes values but the issue is that i don't know the ID/name of the  tag.
I can't use getElementById , getElementByClass etc...

I tried to add a specific CSS class 'SPECIFIC_CSS' but gforms added it to the li tag. I can only identify the value of the checkboxes (Father,Mother,Secretary).

How can I target those specific checkboxes? can i target their values ? How? Do you have another method i didn't think of ?

```
<li id="field_31_3-1-1" class="gfield SPECIFIC_CSS field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible gf_repeater_child_field" data-repeater-parentid="1" data-repeater-repeatid="1" data-repeater-childid="1">

<label class="gfield_label">Checkboxes Test 1</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_checkbox"><ul class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_31_3">


<li class="gchoice_31_3_1">
<input name="input_3.1-1-1" value="Father" id="choice_31_3_1-1-1" tabindex="1" data-repeater-inputid="1" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_1-1-1" id="label_31_3_1">Father</label></li>

<li class="gchoice_31_3_2">
<input name="input_3.2-1-1" value="Mother" id="choice_31_3_2-1-1" tabindex="1" data-repeater-inputid="2" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_2-1-1" id="label_31_3_2">Mother</label></li>

<li class="gchoice_31_3_3">
<input name="input_3.3-1-1" value="Secretary" id="choice_31_3_3-1-1" tabindex="1" data-repeater-inputid="3" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice_31_3_3-1-1" id="label_31_3_3">Secretary</label>
</li></ul></div></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

`document.querySelector('input[value="Father"]').checked = true;`

or if you just want the element without checking it:

`document.querySelector('input[value="Father"]');`

Comment: What if i am using a repeater that duplicate the field and its value? Each time the client repeats the fields a new value ='Father' is made ?

Comment: @YMA981 Assuming that you only have one `<li>` per input labeled "Father" and that you can label each with a specific class (in your example above "SPECIFIC_CSS"), then you could use `document.querySelector('li.SPECIFIC_CSS input[value="Father"]');`

Comment: unfortunately no, the SPECIFIC_CSS assigned in the UI is only assign in the first checkboxes then it is replicated each time the user repeats the field.